# how come bottom padding animation on rotated object causes -DIAGONAL- movement?

Tags: css, animation, rotation

I'm trying to do a little feedback tab on the elft side of my page.
I've created a div, rotated it 90 degrees, and slapped it to the left side of my page. So far so good. Then I wanted to add a little animation on hover. so I increase ONLY the bottom padding a little, but the tab moves diagonally... /:
[Here's a **CodePen** with the problem.](http://www.codepen.io/A-Zak/pen/qoicB)

How do I fix it?!
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you transform an element, unless specified otherwise, the origin is the center. But if you add `padding-bottom`, then you are moving the center down. This causes the rotation to be based around a different point, resulting in diagonal movement.

Try using `transform-origin:0 100%;` to position the transform relative to the bottom-left corner. You'll need to adjust your `left` and `top` values, but you should no longer see problems when you increase the bottom padding.